# Unable to load pickle file

Tags: python, pickle

I was previously able to load a pickle file. I saved a new file under a different name. I am unable to load either the old or the new file. Which is a bummer as it contains data which I have worked hard to scrub.

Here is the code that I use to save:

```
def pickleStore():
    pickle.dump(store, open("...shelf3.p", "wb"))
```

Here is the code that I use to re-load:

```
def pickleLoad():
    store = pickle.load(open(".../shelf3.p","rb" ) )
```

The created file exists, and I run pickleLoad() no errors come up, neither does any variables show in the panel variable explorer. If I try to load a non-existent file, I get a error message.

I am running spyder, python 3.5.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `store = ...` is assigning to a local variable that no longer exists when the function exits. Do you mean to have `global store` at the front of your function, to have it assign to a module-level variable?

Comment: Yes that is my intention. Would there be a reason why I wouldn't want his to be the case?

Comment: well, you aren't actually *doing anything else* in the function you provided -- it just immediately exits and throws away the retrieved content. You might actually demonstrate that you're trying to read that local variable and finding it empty, should that be the case.

Comment: *Face plant* I was being a bit dim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write to a module-level variable from a function, you need to use the `global` keyword:

```
store = None

def pickleLoad():
    global store
    store = pickle.load(open(".../shelf3.p","rb" ) )
```

...or return the value and perform the assignment from module-level code:

```
store = None

def pickleLoad():
    return pickle.load(open(".../shelf3.p","rb" ) )

store = pickleLoad()
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general and more versatile approach I would suggest something like this:

```
def load(file_name):
    with open(simulation, 'rb') as pickle_file:
        return pickle.load(pickle_file)

def save(file_name, data):
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)
```

I have added this snippet to several projects in order to reduce rewriting same code several times.

Comment: What problems does this solve, beyond ensuring that the file descriptor is closed as soon as the block exits (rather than deferring this to happen at garbage collection time)?